# How can I change htaccess file for more patterns redirection?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, friendly-url

I have the following situation. I have a website which is a dictionary, and I was able to create one redirect rule for friendly URLS:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*) /definitie.php?forma=$1&cuvant=$2
```

This works really fine. So httpmywebsitedotcom/definitie.php?forma=form&cuvant=word redirects automatically to httpmywebsitedotcom/form/word

Now, the site has also a different functionality: to show the declination of a noun. For this I have created another php file which gets only one parameter. The long url is:

httpmywebsitedotcom/declinare.php?cuvant=word. This I want to transform in: httpmywebsitedotcom/declinare/word

Any idea how?
I tried a lot of things from the internet, but none worked. The last one I tried is:

```
RewriteRule ^declinare/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) /declinare.php?cuvant=$1
```

Thanks a lot for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your rules like this in your root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^declinare/([\w-]+)/? declinare.php?cuvant=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]*)/?$ definitie.php?forma=$1&cuvant=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Now I have a different one. If I have another option on the site, would that also do the trick. So, besides declinare.php, I also have another one with conjugare.php. Should I just put one line after the other?

RewriteRule ^declinare/([\w-]+)/? declinare.php?cuvant=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^conjugare/([\w-]+)/? conjugare.php?cuvant=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

Comment: You can enter this new rules after `declinare.php` rule.