# Change htaccess for subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a site that works as a Romanian dictionary. Let's call it www.mysite.ro. I managed to do all the redirection for the main site (mysite.ro -> www.mysite.ro, mysite.ro/index.php -> www.mysite.ro) and also for the parameters through this topic of [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995135/how-can-i-change-htaccess-file-for-more-patterns-redirection).

Now I would like to include an english dictionary. For this I have created a subdomain: english.mysite.ro. Now I would like to create the following redirects:

- *english.mysite.ro/index.php* should redirect to *english.mysite.ro*
- *english.mysite.ro/index.php?cuvant=strong&form=care-incepe-cu* ->
  *english.mysite.ro/care-incepe-cu/strong*

My current .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteRule ^declinare/([^/]+)/? declinare.php?cuvant=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^conjugare/([^/]+)/? conjugare.php?cuvant=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]*)/?$ definitie.php?forma=$1&cuvant=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^toatecuvintele\.ro$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.toatecuvintele\.ro$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ "http\:\/\/www\.toatecuvintele\.ro\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^toatecuvintele.ro$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.toatecuvintele\.ro\/" [R=301,L]
```

To this, I tried to add the following line, for my first question, but with no success:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^english.toatecuvintele.ro$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ "http\:\/\/english\.toatecuvintele\.ro\/" [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas would just be great!

Thank you

Comment: Where did you add the new rule? Order matters. If you put it at the end, it will never fire because the non-www -> www redirect takes precedence.

Comment: I put it at the end :(. Where should I put it exactly?

Comment: I tried now different positions: before the first group of `rewrite` rules, then before the first `rewritecond` group then before the second `rewritecond` group. Nothing happens...

Comment: First thing first: Have you altered your dns so that requests to `english.yoursite.ro` get to your server? How have you configured this subdomain on your server? Does this subdomain use the same folder as your main domain, or have you configured a different folder as the www-root of this subdomain?

Comment: _Yes_ to the fist question. _Different folder_ to the second question.